# Node.js Value from Firebase not updating array in time for function call (even with Async Await)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm sure this issue is from my lack of async/await knowledge or general best practices in general. However, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm looking to pull a value from my firestore database, include it into an array of "global variables" and then call it when ever I need it in other modules.  However when I check the array pulled in the test function, it always returns a promise.  The below code is an example of the last thing I tried.

index.js

```
const vars = require('./variables');

test();
async function test() {
  console.log('Expect database value', await vars.global()['lovePizza']);
}
```

variables.js (this is working, array updates)

```
const db = require('./database');

Let globalVars = {
  lovePiza : '',
}
const variables = {
  async global() {
    globalVars['lovePizza'] = (globalVars['lovePizza'] === '') ? db.getLovePizza() : globalVars['lovePizza'];

    return globalVars;
  }
}
module.exports = variables;
```

database.js (this is working, value gets pulled from db)

```
const database = {
  async getLovePizza() {
    const usersRef = db.collection('accounts').doc('user1');

    const doc = await usersRef.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      return doc.data()['lovePizza'];
    }
  }
}
module.exports = database;
```

Terminal Response:

```
Expect database value undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a problem in your variables.js, I hope the problem is solved with these changes, use await before `db.getLovePizza()`

use `try/catch` when you use `async/await`

```
const db = require('./database');
Let globalVars = {
  lovePiza : '',
}
async global() {
  if(globalVars['lovePizza'] === ''){
      try {
       let result = await db.getLovePizza()//use await 
       console.log(result);
       globalVars['lovePizza'] = result
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        //do somthing for error handlig like throw 
      }
  }
  else{
    globalVars['lovePizza'] = globalVars['lovePizza'] //I think there is no need for this
  }
   return globalVars;
}
```

index.js

```
  test() {
  let result = await vars.global()
  console.log('Expect database value', result);// added to question
  console.log('Expect database value', result['lovePizza']);// added to question
}
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that, it helped, but results still come out as undefined.

Your answer helps because now in index.js if I define vars.global() as its own variable then call it again in the console.log, it works.  However, preferably I could refer to it direct using vars.global()['lovePizza'].  Is this not possible?

Comment: your welcome, unfortunately I have no experience in google-cloud-firestore,  can you added the result of `console.log()` like part of the added to my answer, may be I can help you, because type of result should check

Comment: becuase vars,global() function is a async  so first of all you should assign to a variable

Comment: ok well noted, so I must assign to a variable.  thanks so much